# How to delete an element from an array in php without array search?

Tags: php

Delete an element from an array in php without `array_search`

I want to delete an array element from array, but I dont know the array `key` of that element only value is known

It is possible by `array_search` with value, first to find the key and then use `unset`

Is there any inbuilt array function to  remove array element with   array value  ?

Comment: Why can't you use `array_search()`?

Comment: Yes, there is an infinite number of complicated ways to do it, but `array_search` is the most straight-forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only remove element from array only by referencing to this KEY. So you have to get this KEY somehow. The function to get the key for the searched value from array is exactly `array_search()` function which returns KEY for given VALUE.

Comment: An example here would probably be worthwhile, no?

Answer (score 2):

Example showing one way you can do this without using array_search()

```
$myArray = array(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2); 
$knownValue = 3;

$myArray = array_filter(
               $myArray, 
               function($value) use ($knownValue) {
                   return $value !== $knownValue; 
               }
           );
```

Comment: Won't it remove all occurrences of `$knownValue`, if it is repeating. But maybe that is the desired behavior in the question asked.

Comment: @Pushpesh - yes, it will remove all occurrences of $knownValue if there are duplicates... otherwise you need some form of mechanism to identifyu which you want to delete.... but you'd need that however you were trying to remove only one occurrence of several (even array_search() won't necessarily help you there)

Answer (score 2):

Any function that has to *"to remove array element with array value"* will have to perform a loop over every* element looking for the value to delete. Therefore you might as well just add your own `for` loop to do this, or `array_search()` will do this for you.

The reason arrays have keys is so that you can get at values efficiently using that key.

**actually you'd stop looping once you'd found it rather than keep looking, unless there could be duplicates to remove*

Answer (score 0):

The only valid case to not use `array_search` is if you'd like to unset several values. You still need to use keys though. I'd recommend you to iterate through the array and remove fields that match your criteria.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value === $deleteValue)
        unset($array[$key]);
}
```